# Unable to pass data to second view controller

Tags: xml, swift, viewcontroller

I got stuck with a problem over here.
I want to parse text out of an xml file about the weather and send it to a label in the second View Controller. In the first step I do this:

```
var xml = SWXMLHash.parse(urlContent!)


        for elem in xml["data"]["weather"][0]["hourly"][self.indexOfTime]{
            self.chanceRain = (elem["chanceofrain"].element!.text!)

        }

        println(self.chanceRain)
```

(The above is done with SWXMLHash)

After it runs it prints the value without any problems. So the next step is creating the connection between first & second View Controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "btnSubmitSegue"){

        var svc: viewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as viewTwo

        svc.datapassed = "hello " + chanceRain

    } }
```

After running it, the label is "hello". When I run it without hello, so like this it does not display anything. Its kinda weird because the variable chanceRain does print in the log, and "hello" displays in the label but chanceRain doesn't

Is anybody able to help me? If more info is needed please let me know which info/code you need to see.

By the way this isn't all the coding but I'm sure it goes wrong in the code I posted.

**Edit:**

Here is the full code:

```
import UIKit
import SWXMLHash

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

var cellContent = [""]
var indexOfTime = 0
var chanceRain = ""



@IBOutlet var cityInput: UITextField!

func enumerate(indexer: XMLIndexer) {
for child in indexer.children {
    NSLog(child.element!.name)
    enumerate(child)
}
}

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

var url = NSURL(string:            "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?  key=ca89103dfe0a8b844a0a1e1249820&q=" +
      cityInput.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "- ") + "/" + cityInput.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "- ") + "/" + "&num_of_days=2&tp=3&format=xml")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

println(url)

  var xml = SWXMLHash.parse(urlContent!)


     for elem in xml["data"]["weather"][0]["hourly"][self.indexOfTime]{
        self.chanceRain = (elem["chanceofrain"].element!.text!)

        }

        println(self.chanceRain)


    })
    task.resume()

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


if(segue.identifier == "btnSubmitSegue"){


    var svc: viewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as viewTwo

    svc.datapassed = "hallo " + toString(chanceRain) //dit werkt, maar     chanceRain niet..?


  } }





override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

cellContent = ["01:00","04:00","07:00", "10:00", "13:00", "16:00", "19:00",    "22:00"]
}

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

  return cellContent.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default  , reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

cell.textLabel?.text = "\(cellContent[indexPath.row])"

return cell }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

 indexOfTime = indexPath.row



 }



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
}
```

Comment: have you tried printing the chainRain near this line svc.datapassed = "hello " + chanceRain

Comment: @iosDev82 When I print it near that code it doesn't print. The variable chanceRain is a global one and is at default "". When I change that to var chanceRain: String! it crashes

Comment: that means your `chanceRain` is become empty at run time somewhere so debug code and find why it is empty.

Comment: It must have gotten released around that time. At top code you are referring to it as a self.chainRain and down the line you refer it to only as chianRain?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems reasonable, but the details are important.

Some things to check:

Is chanceRain declared as weak? If it is, that's your problem. Get rid of the weak qualifier.

Failing that, check for other things that set your chanceRain variable. You might even add a didSet method to the property and set a breakpoint in the didSet method to see where it's being called.

By the way, the code you posted to parse your XML is kinda silly:

```
for elem in xml["data"]["weather"][0]["hourly"][self.indexOfTime]
{
  self.chanceRain = (elem["chanceofrain"].element!.text!)
}
```

Each time through the for loop, you're replacing the value in chanceRain with a new value. At the end of the loop chanceRain will contain the LAST value. If you only want the last value, write it to only parse the last element. Otherwise, write code that adds up the chances, concatenates them, or whatever is appropriate.

### EDIT:

It sounds like you don't understand about assignments and loops.

Imagine this code

```
var result = String()
for (i in 1..10)
  result = "String \(i)\n"

println(result)
```

What you would see is

> String 10

If you wanted all the strings from 1 to 10, you should write your code like this:

```
var result = String()
for (i in 1..10)
  result = result + "String \(i)\n"

println(result)
```

In that case you would see

> String 1
> String 2
> String 3
> String 4
> String 5
> String 6
> String 7
> String 8
> String 9
> String 10

In the first version the code is replacing the value in result with a new value each time through the loop.

In the second version The code is *concatenating* the new string onto the previous result.

Comment: how am i able to only get the last value?

Comment: Each time through the loop you replace the previous value with the value for that iteration through the loop. At the end, the only thing in chanceRain is the **LAST** value you put there.

Comment: See my edits explaining why. If you still don't understand, spend some time with a playground trying it out.

Comment: the problem is that the prepareforsegue function is not getting the chanceRain variable. for some reason chanceRain only has a value inside the task variable. Does somebody know how to fix that? I tried to fix it in playground but I can't import my  SWXMLHash in it.